# Why don't javascript: URLs work from extensions on Safari?

Tags: safari-extension

I'm building a Safari extensions that fakes a POST by dynamically creating a form using a javascript: URL.

When I try to load this URL like this:

tab.url = "javascript:" + foo;

I get "Safari can't use JavaScript for this action"

I tried doing something simple like:

tab.url = "javascript:alert('hello')";

and I get the same error.

I tried pasting my URL directly into the URL bar and it works fine.

Is there any reason Safari doesn't allow extensions to load javacript: URLs? OR is there some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, you can use a data URL instead:

```
data:text/html,<body></body><script>alert('hello');</script>
```

Works just as well as the javascript: URL. You need to make sure you include the body, though, just in case your bookmarklet depends on there being a body.

I still don't know why javascript: URLs work in from Safari extensions, though.